# How to fetch the property data from RESTful API using Angular 2 by observables?? Soory, I am new to this

Tags: angular, angular2-services

## my Api look like this

Url:prabin.hello.com/api/news/latest-breaking

{

```
"success": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "id": "13958",
        "title": "Rare vultures make appearance in Myagdi highlands",
        "introText": "BENI, Jan 29: Disappearing species of vultures are gradually appearing in hilly and mountainous parts of the district after the district was declared diclofenac-free last year.",
        "featuredImage": "",
        "publishOn": "2017-01-29T16:45:00+0000",
        "publishOnDate": "Sunday, 29 Jan 2017"
    },
    {
        "id": "13957",
        "title": "Sanjay Leela Bhansali assaulted by fringe group for ‘distorting facts’",
        "introText": "The attack on ace filmmaker Sanjay Leela Bhansali on the sets of his upcoming film Padmavati in Jaipur by activists of a Rajput organisation has left many fraternity members “appalled”. They have demanded a strong action by the government.",
        "featuredImage": "http://www.myrepublica.com/uploads/media/Sanjay-Leela-Bhansali.gif",
        "publishOn": "2017-01-29T16:05:00+0000",
        "publishOnDate": "Sunday, 29 Jan 2017"
    },
```

### and my service component looks like this

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BreakingnewsApiService {


  constructor(private http: Http) {

   }
   fetchNews(): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('http://prabin.hello.com/api/news/latest-breaking')
                            .map(response => response.json())
   }


}
```

## and my breakingnews componet look like this ##

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { BreakingnewsApiService} from '../breakingnews-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breakingnews',
  templateUrl: './breakingnews.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breakingnews.component.scss']
})
export class BreakingnewsComponent implements OnInit {
 public items;

  constructor(private _breakingnewsApiService: BreakingnewsApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this._breakingnewsApiService.fetchNews()
        .subscribe(
             items => this.items = items.data,
             Error => console.log('error fetching news')
            );
             }

}
```

#### and my html componet look like this

```
    <div class="main-content">
      <ol>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items " class="post">
          <item class="item-block" itemID="{{ item.id }}"></item>
        </li> 
      </ol>


<`/div>`
```

#### all I need to is fetching the  intro text and id property and using that id to call another url to find the details of the news

Thank you in advance ###

Comment: Where's your problem? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you presented looks like it would work, as long as you have defined **BreakingnewsApiService** in the providers list of your module.

In a very simple case where you only have an app.module, just **import** **BreakingnewsApiService** into that file, and add it to the list of **providers**[1].

Your component constructor argument **_breakingnewsApiService** only tells angular which type of service you would like injected. Adding the class to the providers list, allows angular to understand that when you ask for a **BreakingnewsApiService** it just simply use that (rather than, say, an instance value you have created while constructing it specially, or a subclass, or a constant, ...)

[1] https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#registering-providers-in-an-ngmodule

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are rendering HTML even before your observables resolve and returns with data. One way to solve this kind of issue is to have an *ngIf in your parent div so your HTML will be only rendered once you have the data from observable.

```
 <div *ngIf="items" class="main-content">
      <ol>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items " class="post">
          <item class="item-block" itemID="{{ item.id }}"></item>
        </li> 
      </ol>
</div>
```